# Java:Transforming multiple XML file on single XSL file to generate single output XMLfile

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am in need to transform multiple input XML files into a single output XML using single XSL. 
I am able to transform single XML on single XSL file using java JAXP. Below is the code I used, but I have no idea how to pass multiple input XML files to single XSL file

```
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource("Transform_LineSequenceNumber1.xsl");

        StreamSource in = new StreamSource("Transform_LineSequenceNumber1-Source.xml");
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult("Output.xml");

        try {
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
            transformer.transform(in, out);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Well, which XSLT 2 processor do you use exactly, how do you identify the files, is that a finite number of known files you can pass in as parameter values? Or do you want to use a source directory? If the processor is Saxon 9 then inside your XSLT you can use `collection('folder?select=*.xml')` to read in all XML files in folder as a sequence of document nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `collection` function XSLT has the standard function `document` to load additional xml in a stylesheet.

For example you can *store* it in a varablie then apply templates to that variable

```
<xsl:variabe name='another_file' select='document("foo.xml")/' />
```

A detailed [example](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xslt/ch07_02.htm) taken from the o'reilly XSLT book.

Answer (score 0):

Use ByteArrayOutputStream (baos) to write transformation of each file to a stream.
get the baos.toString() value after each file is processed, and write that via an external FileWriter. Reset the baos after each iteration.